# Download ZIP from Amazon S3 does not preserve timestamp when extracting in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

When I download a ZIP file from Amazon S3 and extract it using Java, it does not preserve the original timestamp of the file inside the ZIP.
Why? Here's the uncompress Java code:

```
public void unzipFile(String zipFile, String newFile) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        //close resources
        fos.close();
        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically, I want the timestamp of the file inside of the zip file, say file X has JAN-01-2010 to be preserved. But file X's is overwridden with the timestamp of the ZIP file, which has SEP-20-2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are putting the contents of the Zip File into a new File.

You could try something like:

```
public void unzipFile(String zipFile, String outputFolder){
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        File folder = new File(outputFolder);
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
           }

        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while(ze!=null){
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

            //create all non exists folders
            //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
            newFile.setLastModified(ze.getTime());
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }

        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Pulled from: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/ With Modifications to add Modified Time.

Comment: Basically, I want the timestamp of the file inside of the zip file, say file X has JAN-01-2010 to be preserved. But file X's is overwridden with the timestamp of the ZIP file, which has SEP-20-2013.

Comment: Modified it based off an example from another site. It uses ZipInputStream and ZipEntry where the ZipEntry does contain the modification time of the entry.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now I see how ZipEntry is used properly. Thanks!

Comment: `new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs()` should really be `newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`.